# Lambda capture by value and non copyable object

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, copy-constructor

I'm trying to understand the implications of the lambda expression in the code snippet below.

The lambda expression captures variables by value rather than by reference otherwise the local variable `message` is destroyed when `foo` exits.

What I don't understand is the capture of `m_impl`. How is it captured by value if the copy ctor of `Impl` is deleted? Please can someone enlighten me?

```
void Foo::foo(std::shared_ptr<std::string> message)
{
    m_impl->m_thread.send([=] { m_impl->handleMessage(message); });
}
```

`handleMessage` is declared as:

```
void handleMessage(std::shared_ptr<std::string> message)
```

and `m_impl` as:

```
std::unique_ptr<Impl> m_impl;
```

`Impl` has its copy constructor and assignment operator deleted.

Comment: I'm not certain at all, but my guess is it would be moved instead of copied, so the original 'copy' of m_impl is invalid after creation of the lambda

Comment: it's `this` that is captured by value, not `m_impl` as you suspect. `m_impl` is accessed indirectly through that implicit `this` pointer

Comment: yep: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/23d0c42ff53cd8c4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The things that can be captured are:

- local variables, by value or reference;
- in a class member function, the `this` pointer, by value.

Member variables are not captured, although capturing `this` effectively captures them by reference. By specifying a capture default, `this` will be captured if you refer to any class member within the lambda body, allowing access to that member.

Presumably, `m_impl` is a member variable, so that's what's happening here.

Comment: `m_impl` is a member variable. Are you saying that `this` is captured by reference even though the capture clause is `[=]`? 'Foo' also has a deleted copy ctor.

Comment: @ksl: `this` is always captured by value. But it's a pointer, so capturing it by value has a similar effect to capturing the object's member variables by reference. Nothing is copied apart from the value of the pointer.